# Reportlab 2 or more pages per file

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

How can I generate a PDF with two or more pages with reportlab? I've been unable to find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`canvas.showPage()`

will force a new page (even though it sounds like its showing a page,)

(assuming you are using the canvas)

if you are using flowables I think there is a PageBreak flowable

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just keep `.append()`ing stuff and it will break the pages automatically once it get's too large for a single page, or you can force a page break by doing:

```
.append(PageBreak())
```